# How can i checked the radiobutton list with value using jquery

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

i have the radio button list and a textbox with the code below:

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Enabled" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Disabled" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>

   <asp:TextBox ID="enable" runat="server" value="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now i want the 1st list in the radiobutton list to be seleted/checked but mu jquery code doesnt work. Anyone can help me? 
I write my jquery code as below :

```
    if($('#<%= enable.ClientID %>').val()=="Enabled")
        $('#<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>').val(1);
   else($('#<%= enable.ClientID %>').val()=="Disabled")
        $('#<%= RadioButtonList.ClientID %>').val(2);
```

Comment: `if($('#<%= enable.ClientID %>').val() == "Enable")` try

Comment: `.val` is a function: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if($('#<%= enable.ClientID %>').val()=="Enable")
        $('#<%= roleDropDownList.ClientID %> input[value="1"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: The default value is always enabled .. For that to happen , you need to write the change event for the textbox.. Check my Updated code...

Answer (score 1):

.val is a method and not a property..

Correct syntax is **.val()**

Also looks like your RadioButtonList id is **RadioButtonList**..

But you are trying to select $('#<%= roleDropDownList.ClientID %>')

```
   if($('[id*=enable]').val() == "Enabled"){
        $('[id*=RadioButtonList] :radio[value="1"] ').prop('checked', true);
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$(function() {
    $('#<%= enable.ClientID %>').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(' #<%=  enable.ClientID %> ').val();
        if (val == "Enabled") {
          $('#<%=RadioButtonList.ClientID%> :radio[value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else if( val == "Dnabled" ) {
          $('#<%=RadioButtonList.ClientID%> :radio[value="2"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }).change();
});
```

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vsssY/)

Comment: *".val is a function and not a method.."* What?

Comment: Strictly speaking it is a property, but its value is a function, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var set_value=2;
  $('#RadioButtonList').filter("[value='"+set_value+"']").attr("checked","checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$('#<%= enable.ClientID %> input').click(function() {
    alert('Selected Value: '+$("#<%= enable.ClientID %> input:radio:checked").val());
});
```